# Vote early, vote often!

Tags: discussion, participation, voting

Like other Beta sites, such as [Operations Research](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/vote-early-vote-often), [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/5) and [Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/vote-early-vote-often), I think it would be a good idea to advertise this voting principle to the Cardano community. This is a condensed version of [Atwood's "Vote Early, Vote Often" post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/).

> "I cannot state this strongly enough. Voting is *absolutely critical* to the formation of a healthy SE site. And this is never more true than in Private and early Public beta. 
>  **You don't have to agree with an answer to vote it up!**"

Quoting Robert Cartaino from chat:

> "Vote, vote, vote. Encourage others to vote, vote, vote. On good content, leave signposts ("If you like this, please vote it up. It's important for the community!")-- in both meta and the main site. Maybe a few meta posts informing the users of the important of that type of participation. You are empowered a lot more than you know."

---

<sub>Credits to [Dawny33](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/46119).</sub>