# Could a CM help us make some tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

There are ones which I think would be appropriate so far:

- "non-fungible-token" for [nft](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nft).
- "transactions-per-second" for [tps](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tps).
- "decentralized-applications" for [dapps](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapps).

Perhaps also "application-programming-interface" for [api](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) though it's much more well-known what API means.

Also I think the following one might be appropriate (but rather than making an entire synonym:

- "apple-operating-system" for [macos](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)

  - otherwise it looks like "macos" not "macOS"
  - [this is the tag we use at Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-operating-system) which might actually be better since it covers both iOS and macOS

Comment: API is fine - I actually have no clue what it stands for but I know what an API is. :P Can make a synonym with API as the main tag, though if that makes sense. Is [tag:dapps] actually even correct or should it be hyphenated? (d-apps) - I've done tps and dapps but I'm not sure about nft and api. Not sure about macos - I think some sites do mac-os instead. But I'll let y'all figure that out. Ping me once y'all have some decisions.

Comment: @Catija dapps is correct, without the hyphen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decentralized_application#Characteristics. API is just application-programming-interface so it could have a synonym pointing to the full-length version just to make things extra clear and remove any possible ambiguity: the only disadvantage I think I know about longer tag names, is that when you put tags in a chat room's description, there's a limit to how many total characters you can have (rather than a limit on the # of tags). What about NFT, you wouldn't make a synonym for that?

Comment: NFT is like API - I think more people know the term NFT than they do the long version. Not sure which way the synonyms should go.

Comment: @Catija We do type NFT more often than we type it all out, but I thought for tag synonyms it's recommended to have the full version as much as possible, for example here (DFT and ab-initio are what we say 99.9% of the time, but the tags went the other way): https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28/5

Comment: The question is - what would a novice know. While the site is for experts and newcomers alike, the newer people need to be able to find tags for things when they may not know the short term for things. I think (and I may be wrong) that API and NFT are both pretty commonly known, even by novices. But let me know what y'all think. See - https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27/2

Comment: @Catija API is certainly known across the network by non-experts. NFT is only going to be known by the domain experts. In either case though, when they type "api" for the tag, it will re-direct them to application-programming-interface, and likewise for "nft", so if a novice only knows to search for "api" they will still find the right tag. By the way: this "[vote early, vote often](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/149)" post was "featured" during the Private Beta for Drones, Matter Modeling, and Operations Research. Could it be for Cardano too since we don't have anything else?

Comment: I have edited the tag for catalyst and when I hover over it now, it displays "Caradano's innovation and funding platform"  maybe these could be handled the same way. It is a balance between looking professional and helpful to those unfamiliar with the acronyms.

Comment: Thanks @gRebel. That's different from [tag synonyms](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) though.

Comment: The explanation of Tag synonyms says that it silently converts to the preferred tag.  So it's great for things like consistent misspellings or variants.  I stand by my original comment.  Using it to convert commonly used abbreviations to something friendlier to users unfamiliar with the abbreviation seems like using it for the wrong purpose and the hover functionality is more appropriate.

Comment: @gRebel I totally felt that way a year ago! See the link I gave about trying to turn density-functional-theory to dft, but that was denied by Catija and a year later I agree with her.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the appropriate pattern should be to follow what the community terminology is.

e.g. If no posts are writing "non-fungible token" in their text but are using NFT liberally, it is more appropriate to have "nft" as the tag and the hover-mouse expand to "Non-fungible token"

The same applies to the other abbreviations commonly used in the community.